# How to schedule Crontab in Linux to run for every minutes of X?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to schedule the crontab to run the job for every minutes of X? For example let say X here means for '5'.

I want to schedule the crontab to run the job for every:

- 12.05AM, 12.15AM, 12.25AM, ... 2.35AM, 2.45AM, ...

If X here means for '3', then the job should run for every:

- 3.03AM, 3.13AM, 3.23AM ... 6.23PM, 6.33PM, ...

Currently, doing it manually by waiting for that specific minutes and schedule it to run every 10 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

If X is 5, I will just do it this way in crontab -e:

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * run anytask
```

If X is 3, then:

```
3,13,23,33,43,53 * * * * run anytask
```